# Running an RLE algorithm results in no data on BMP

Tags: c++, image, encoding, compression

I am trying to implement an RLE algorithm into my compression program. Currently I have the image being Quantized then being passed to the runLengthEncode function. The RLE functions at the bottom worked for me on string data when calling it by

```
std::ifstream inputFile(inputFile, std::ios_base::binary);
```

and

```
std::ofstream outputFile(outputFileName + "_RLEcompressed." + savedExtension, std::ios_base::binary);
```

but it doesn't seem to work when passed arbitrary data. Am I supposed to run RLE encoding on a char* instead? Would this allow the data to be more arbitrary? I've also tested in on other images that were not quantized prior, so I know the issue still prevails.

**RLE Functions:**

```
/*
* Run Length Encoding
* This function uses the RLE algorithm to encode/compress data
*/
void runLengthEncode(std::istream &is, std::ostream &os){    
    char ch; //Buffering character
    char prev_ch; //Holds previous characters
    int count = 1; //Counts number of chars in a run
    is.get(prev_ch); //Get first char of input stream
    while (is.get(ch)) {
        if(ch != prev_ch) { //Character has changed from a run
            os << count << prev_ch;
            count = 0; //Reset          
        }
        count++;
        prev_ch = ch; //Set prev_ch to char just read
    } os << count << prev_ch; //Reads last character to output
}

/*
* Run Length Decoding
* This function uses the RLE algorithm to decode/decompress data
*/
void runLengthDecode(std::istream &is, std::ostream &os){
    char ch; //Buffering character
    while (is.get(ch)) {
        int numToPrint = ch - '0'; //Gets number of char
        is.get(ch); //Gets character to print
        while(numToPrint--){
            os << ch;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your decoder assumes runs are 9 characters or shorter.  Your encoder will encode runs longer than that.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I see, but the encoder itself doesn't seem to work either. For example, a 500KB BMP image leaves me with 1KB of data when encoded. Contrary to text files which are produce the correctly encoded data.